# How to adjust width based on number of images

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

I have a container that contains random amount of images(1-3) and text.

If there is one image, the image needs to take the whole width, if there are two half the width etc

How can I implement such a thing?

Here is my code -

```css
.images {
    display: flex;
}

.images img {
    max-height: 520px;
}
```

```html
<div className="container">
    <div className="user-container">
        <div className="avatar">M</div>
        <div className="user-data">
            <div>Username</div>
            <div>Time</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div className="content">
   Some Random Text
    </div>
    <div className="images">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/222/200/300">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/231/200/300">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell the images in question to resize themselves evenly. For this you set `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` both to `1` (you can use the shorthand `flex: 1 1` for this). After that also tell the images to start filling the available place from a size of `0`

```css
.images img {
  flex: 1 1;
  max-height: 512px;
  width: 0;
}
```

This will space out all your images, regardless of how many you have.

If you do not specify the `width: 0` the images will try to take their intrinsic width, resulting in overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply achieve this by using flex.

Set the parent to `display: flex`, then set the same `flex` to the childs,
the items will grow or shrink to fit the space available in its flex container.

[flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox)
[flex property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex)

```
.images {
    display: flex;
}

.images img {
    flex: 1
}
```

Example based on your code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-fire-gjr1db?file=/style.css